# Migrating from log4j to log4j2 - properties file configuration

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have a Java application which is using **log4j** configured as below.

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R
log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File = /trace.log
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

I would like to migrate to log4j2 with the same configuration as above. Haven't found anything related to log4j2 properties configuration file as this support recently included.

How would be my **log4j2.properties** file with the same configuration above ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is what I constructed after going through the documentation and worked.

```
rootLogger.level = INFO
property.filename = trace.log
appenders = R, console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

appender.R.type = RollingFile
appender.R.name = File
appender.R.fileName = ${filename}
appender.R.filePattern = ${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.R.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.R.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.R.policies.type = Policies
appender.R.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.R.policies.time.interval = 1

rootLogger.appenderRefs = R, console

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.R.ref = File
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use this to convert from Log4J.properties (v1.2) to log4j2.xml as below:

1) Convert from v1.2 properties to v1.2XML using this converter: https://log4j-props2xml.appspot.com/

2) Convert from v1.2 XML to v2.0 XML (i.e. Log4j2.xml) using the procedure provided on this link: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Answer (score 4):

Log4j2 supports .properties files but they have changed property syntax. You can check their [manual here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#Properties) it covers all you need to create new configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old issue but for the sake of history:

Since Log4j2 2.13.0 there is an ***experimental*** feature for Log4j 1 configuration files:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/compatibility.html

Related JIRA issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-63

Answer (score -3):

You can use this wonderful frontend web to convert you properties to a XML
http://log4j-props2xml.appspot.com/

## Resulting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="R" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="File" value="/trace.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="R"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

---

Comment: again this is log4j not log4j2. I need log4j2 configuration in properties file.